# Unknown white border around my content

Tags: html, css, margin

I've created an utterly simple page with only a few elements. I have a white border around my 'content div' and can't figure out what is causing it. It is appearing only top and left of my content. I've tried removing it with .body { border: 0; }, but that did not help. Also a few other things with regard to my CSS, but solved it.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <title>Olivera Miletic graphic desig</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mainText">
            <p> OLI<span class="secondColor">APPARENTLY </p>
             <p class="stayTuned"> SOON. STAY TUNED. </p>
          </div>
                  <div>
                      <p class="meanWhile"> meanwhile <a href="http://www.oliveramiletic.com" target="_blank"> WORK </a> / <a href="https://www.behance.net/olivera_m" target="_blank"> BE </a> / <a href="https://twitter.com/oliapparently" target="_blank"> TW </a> / <a href="mailto:miletic.olivera@gmail.com" > MAIL </a>
                      </p>
                 </div>
          </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #6600cc;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 50px;
    display: box;
}

.body {
    margin: 0;
}

.mainText {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 64px;
    color: #FF0066;
    font-weight: bolder;
    line-height: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 70px;

}

.secondColor {
    color: #00ccff;
}

.stayTuned {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.meanWhile {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1yL1ta5x/ and the code:

Also, would appreciate advice how to optimize it for, at least, mobile and desktop views of the webpage and/or any other optimization to my code is welcome. I am an absolute beginner, so bear with me. Thanks.

Regards,

Comment: The white border is the margin from the `<body>` element. set it to zero and it goes away

Comment: Margins from body. U set style for '.body' which is a class and not for element body

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some browsers/frameworks/environments add default `margin`, `padding` values to either the `body` or the `html`.

You have to override the `margins`/`padding` to the `html` or `body` for the white space to disappear.

Just add the following:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

To answer your second question as to why there is scroll on your `container` div, this happens because the div occupies 100% `width` and `height` of its parent and also occupies the *20px* `padding-top`  and *50px* `padding-left`.
Hence the `container` div overflows its parent thus producing a scroll.

A general fix would be to apply `box-sizing: border-box` to `container` so that the `padding` is included in the `width` and `height`.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #6600cc;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Check updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1yL1ta5x/1/

I would suggest you to read more about [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), and the [css box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model) as a whole.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not try to override the padding of if, only the margin.

Comment: Also, if you dont my second question. I am able to scroll up/down and left/right which I figured I would solve by setting width and height to 100% within my content div (my assumption that the browser size would be picked up and there would be no scrolling possible). 

Have you an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Not only did your answer fix my problem, but your through explanation with links is gold to me! Thank you again @nashcheez

Answer (score 4):

Remove the .body and replace it to body.
.body is applied to the class named body, while you want to select the tag, which would be just body.

Alternatively, add class="body" to your body tag.