# Removing white stripes in fullscreen img

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to make a landing page and I have a problem. There are some white stripes all around the `<img>`, it [looks like this](https://gyazo.com/22954474a7ba0cb576728fd1c1aa2ef8).

I would like the picture to be full-screen, without any stripes etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Szafranowka - Apartments & Restaurant </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="background">
            <img src="background.jpg" id="background"> </img>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's CSS:

```css
#container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#background
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown white border around my content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655242/unknown-white-border-around-my-content)

Answer (score 3):

There is padding automatically applied to the body.

Just add this to your css

```
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Edit: Solution to follow up in comments

You will need to remove the `<img>` tag and change your background div in your css

```
#background
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: url("background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: After doing that, it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/408a9eb76f57ce43500c29a88d895edd

Any idea how to remove the bottom, veeery big stripe? :)

Comment: I would say thats because the image height isn't long enough to cover the whole page. I will add the solution to this in my answer.

Comment: It is possible to stretch the image without having to turn it into a div with background image. No support on IE and older Edge versions, though.

Comment: Is this possible while maintaining its aspect ratio? I have always just reverted to setting it as the background.

Comment: You can see it in action in the snippet I attached to an answer here. `background-size: cover` does not maintain aspect ratio or makes sure the whole image parts are visible either, it zooms from the center (50% 50%) and successfully covers the whole area no matter how small the image is. You can only control the origin using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin or a parent container that decides sizes.

Comment: Hello once again :D I dont know why, but when I've deleted <img> and put it into background :url("background.jpg"); all I get is a pure, white site. Its like CSS cannot load the background.jpg

Comment: I would say it does maintain aspect ratio, but it will absolutely cut off part of the image. I agree that your solution is actually better. Jan Szafran I would take a look at Ravenous' codepen.

Answer (score 1):

By default, each HTML tag has a browser-predefined appearance/style, in your case, body has `margin: 8px` on Chrome, for example. You need to reset all of those predefined styling rules in order not to have surprises, read about CSS resets at https://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Moreover, in order to stretch the image to cover all the visible area, you need to make sure `body` has `width: 100vw;` (viewport width) and `height: 100vh;` (viewport height) and everything else has `100%` on both or inherits them from their parents.

Working snippet at https://codepen.io/Raven0us/pen/KZQejX

Comment: Is there now a chance to make it "Responsive"?

Comment: It is responsive, if you check my snippet, resizing won't affect the fact that the image covers the whole area. If by 'responsive' you mean having the image stretching (covering whole area) and still showing all the parts of it, it is not possible without losing a lot of quality. Check how it looks with `object-fit: contain;` instead of `object-fit: cover;` on smaller screens. It will look better to have this on mobiles as height is usually twice or more than width.

Comment: You need to wrap that in a media query so it applies `contain` on mobiles only and it keeps `cover` on tablets+, including desktop.

Comment: I get it, what about that: I would like to achieve smth like this: https://gyazo.com/6b9fb9042820d9ef9b27cb054c622b92 using only html and css code? Cuz when I try to apply the words on graphics, it looks horrible, words are stretched and pixeled.

Comment: Of course, applying the words on graphics is really 2000s unless 1) you are a lazy developer,  2) the ones who will maintain the site got really good Photoshop skills and can provide altered versions for multiple devices/breakpoints, 3) you dont care about responsiveness.

Comment: You can easily position 2 titles on top of the image with `position: absolute;`. If your example is what you are trying to reach, gluing 2 images in one single image is a wrong approach. You need to have 2 different image containers with a 50% width each and place the caption on each of them. This way, the caption will always be on top of the image it represents and on mobiles you can just make them a column (basically splitting them vertically than horizontally).

Answer (score 0):

The browser applies its own default styles to websites that you can alter with your own css. Take a look at this [cheat sheet](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

**An Easy fix for your issue is to add css:**

```
body{
   margin:0;
}
```